# Mod Re-Write Struggling With Rule Not Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So after a lot of testing - I've started to figure out my problems but still can't get the rewrite to work.

This is how my htaccess file looks now.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^schemdetail/id/(.*)$ schematicdetails?id=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abfielder.com/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Rule 1 is the one I'm having problems with

```
RewriteRule ^schemdetail/id/(.*)$ schematicdetails?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

My understanding is now if I type this url into my browser

https://abfielder.com/schemdetail/id/158

I should get

https://abfielder.com/schematicdetails?id=158

The test of this here

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

Tells me my rules are ok.

And rules 2 and 3 are working fine.

However when I try and access

https://abfielder.com/schemdetail/id/158

I essentially get the page not found error.

Comment: So what exactly does "not working" mean? 404? 500? ...?

Comment: You rather _should_ do these things in opposite order - rule of thumb it, more specific things first, less specific things later. Since your middle block should only do something if what was requested with `.php` appended matches an existing file, that probably does no harm here - but it is better to do things in a logical order to begin with, especially if you might have to more rewrite stuff later.

Comment: You have a partial overlap between your fake URL and the actually existing file here - so try and disabled `MultiViews`, that often interferes in such situations.

Comment: So tried a couple of things - firstly you can see what the outcome is by clicking on the friendly link (it's a work safe website, just displaying minecraft schematics)

I've tried rewriting the file so

RewriteRule ^schematicdetails/id/(.*)$ schematicdetails.php?id=$1 [L]

is above the rule that sorts out removing the .php extension which in theory looks like it should work but when trying the "friendly link" in my original post, I still get a blank page with broken images.

Comment: `/schematicdetails/foo/158` shows the exact same thing as `/schematicdetails/id/158` - but the former can not have been affected by your RewriteRule, it doesn't match the pattern. Which speaks for my suspicion, that it is probably MultiViews that made the server map this request to the file `schematicdetails.php` to begin with.

Comment: I think you were partly right with the multi view so I've changed the url slightly. By disabling multiview it broke everything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok think I've finally fixed this for anyone else who is having issues with mod rewrite where they wish to have a rule to remove the file extension and other rewrites working together the order matters. Lastly if you're on a shared host type thing you may also need to set the rewrite base. This is how my htaccess file looks now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^schemdetail/id/(.*)$ schematicdetails?id=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abfielder.com/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This allows me to have url's without the .php extension.

It also allows for

schemdetail/id/100 to be translated into schematicdetails?id=100